# Get-Members for jagged array

Tags: powershell

How do you determine the unique members of a jagged array in powershell?

```
$jagged='{
    "id": "1",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Name1",
            "purpose": "purpose1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "purpose": "purpose2"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "purpose": "purpose3",
            "user": "3"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "purpose": "purpose4"
        }
    ]
}' | convertfrom-json
```

Get-Member probably only considers the first element

```
PS C:\> $jagged.data| get-member  |where {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty"}


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name    MemberType   Definition             
----    ----------   ----------             
id      NoteProperty string id=1            
name    NoteProperty string name=Name1      
purpose NoteProperty string purpose=purpose1
```

There are other elements with different members

```
PS C:\> $jagged.data[2]| get-member  |where {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty"}


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name    MemberType   Definition             
----    ----------   ----------             
id      NoteProperty string id=3            
purpose NoteProperty string purpose=purpose3
user    NoteProperty string user=3
```

I want to find out if the data I am using is jagged or not and also what all of the members (and types) are.
The data I work with is returned as JSON from a third party webservice so I can't realistically predict when it might change or what the changes will look like.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is here as PSA for anyone looking for similar and hopefully will be answered by a powershell guru that knows the proper (and likely simple) method.

```
function Get-Jagged-Members {  
    @($Input)| %{get-member -inputobject $_ |where {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty"}} | select Name,@{n="Definition"; e={ if($_.Definition -match "\S+") {$Matches[0]}}} |group Name, Definition|sort Count|select Name,Count
}

PS C:\> $jagged.data | Get-Jagged-Members

Name            Count
----            -----
name, string        1
user, string        1
id, string          4
purpose, string     4
```

It does the job (for now)..